# Firebase Database Query combining orderByChild and startAt returns nothing

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to query the firebase database with the following query:

```
Query test = mDatabase.orderByChild("creation_date").startAt("-L9H3X-qZZt5WiAdsOKE");
```

My data looks like this:

```
-L9H2ea9Ygt0pD5f17Ze
    creation_date: 
        20180904
    post_id:
        -L9H2ea9Ygt0pD5f17Ze

-L9H3Dmw9gn9lUOV10hK
    creation_date: 
        20180403
    post_id:
        -L9H3Dmw9gn9lUOV10hK

-L9H3OiIzjegJJuuFSfB
    creation_date: 
        20180302
    post_id:
        -L9H3OiIzjegJJuuFSfB

-L9H3X-qZZt5WiAdsOKE
    creation_date: 
        20180404
    post_id:
        -L9H3X-qZZt5WiAdsOKE

-L9JmFch2lnftlMHHiQd
    creation_date: 
        20180405
    post_id:
        -L9JmFch2lnftlMHHiQd

-L9JueI5x9oFRhOX6a3G
    creation_date: 
        20180405
    post_id:
        -L9JueI5x9oFRhOX6a3G
```

I know that after ordering it looks like this:

```
-L9H3OiIzjegJJuuFSfB
    creation_date: 
        20180302
    post_id:
        -L9H3OiIzjegJJuuFSfB

-L9H3Dmw9gn9lUOV10hK
    creation_date: 
        20180403
    post_id:
        -L9H3Dmw9gn9lUOV10hK

-L9H3X-qZZt5WiAdsOKE
    creation_date: 
        20180404
    post_id:
        -L9H3X-qZZt5WiAdsOKE

-L9JmFch2lnftlMHHiQd
    creation_date: 
        20180405
    post_id:
        -L9JmFch2lnftlMHHiQd

-L9JueI5x9oFRhOX6a3G
    creation_date: 
        20180405
    post_id:
        -L9JueI5x9oFRhOX6a3G

-L9H2ea9Ygt0pD5f17Ze
    creation_date: 
        20180904
    post_id:
        -L9H2ea9Ygt0pD5f17Ze
```

I would expect the query to return the last four elements, but it dosent return anything.

I have also added an index on the firebase security rules.

Can anyone help me figure out what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to order by the value of the child:

```
Query test = mDatabase.orderByChild("creation_date").startAt(20180904);
```

This is `-L9H3X-qZZt5WiAdsOKE` the random key which is parent node of child `creation_date`

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I don't why did not think of this myself.

Comment: it's fine no problem!